# How do I get only a shadowed property, not the base property, to get JSON serialized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jsonserializer

In my ASP.NET MVC web application, I am using the built in `Controller.Json()` method to serialize an object and send it back to the client in response to an AJAX call. The class of the object being serialized inherits from another class with some shared property names. This is intentional, as I need the property names to match for some reflection that's happening. I am "shadowing" those properties in the derived class so that they can be a different type from their same-name counterpart in the base class. Here's a simplified example:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal CleanUpHours { get; set; }
    public decimal InstallHours { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedModel : BaseModel
{
    public new BucketHoursWithCalculations CleanUpHours { get; set; }
    public new BucketHoursWithCalculations InstallHours { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize an instance of `DerivedModel`, my JSON object on the client contains only the `decimal` versions of `CleanUpHours` and `InstallHours`, not my custom class `BucketHoursWithCalculations`.

Inspecting the object in Visual Studio before it gets serialized shows both the base and derived versions of those properties, as shown here (please excuse all the extra properties — my sample classes above are more simplified than what I'm actually using, but the principle is the same):

[image: Visual Studio]

Here's what that object looks like on the client once it's serialized into JSON:

[image: ng-inspector in Chrome]

As you can see, the derived/shadowed properties were not serialized, and the base properties were, but only in the cases where there was a name conflict (for example, the `Title` property in the base model serialized just fine).

How can I serialize only the shadowed properties where there's a name conflict? I don't believe changing the access modifiers (i.e. from `public` to `protected` or something) on the base properties will work in my case, because the `BaseModel` is used by Entity Framework, and must have public properties. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about decorating the unneeded properties with ```[NonSerialized()]``` attribute?

Comment: @uncoder Unfortunately that attribute doesn't work on inherited classes, which is where the unwanted properties live

Comment: You're not shadowing the properties, you are hiding them. You have two completely separate instances of a variable named CleanUpHours and InstallHours. According to JSON, which is purely based on strings, which one should get serialized where? You shouldn't have two different object types with the same name.

Comment: What about using `BaseModel<THours>` as the base class and inheriting classes can specify whether they want to use `decimal` or `BucketHoursWithCalculations` as the type?

Comment: @dana that sounds promising. Can you show me a brief example?

Comment: @JacobStamm - I just added an answer with my idea. Please let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: @Dispersia shadowing and hiding are the same thing. If I am wrong in this  understanding, please link some documentation to me so I can alter the title of my question. As for your view that I shouldn't have two different object types with the same name, I don't see a problem with it. The compiler allows it, it allows me to marshal around data dynamically using reflection, and it's easy to understand. There are no discernible downsides in my use case, other than the technical issue I'm running into (which is a problem with the serializer, not the inheritance chain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is to define type parameter on the base model that is used for the hours properties.  Then, define derived models for `decimal` and `BucketHoursWithCalculations`.  I would be interested to see how `BucketHoursWithCalculations` serializes to JSON, but in any case the `CleanUpHours` and `InstallHours` properties should be serialized.

```
// use a type parameter on the base model that must be specified
// in derived models.
public class BaseModel<THours>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public THours CleanUpHours { get; set; }
    public THours InstallHours { get; set; }
}

// hours are specified as decimals
public class DecimalModel : BaseModel<decimal>
{
}

// hours are specified as BucketHoursWithCalculations    
public class BucketHoursWithCalculationsModel : BaseModel<BucketHoursWithCalculations>
{
}

// usage
DecimalModel d = new DecimalModel();
d.CleanUpHours = 1.0M; // CleanUpHours is a decimal here

BucketHoursWithCalculationsModel b = new BucketHoursWithCalculationsModel();
b.CleanUpHours = new BucketHoursWithCalculations();
b.CleanUpHours.SomeProperty = 1.0M;
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! It seems Microsoft's serializer just doesn't know how to handle shadowed properties, and this answer goes around that issue perfectly. https://s28.postimg.org/uaxvwcmrx/2017_01_06_19_23_44.png